# Updated stuff with Updatemanager problem

Tags: updates

I thought I needed to update stuff because of my computer randomly logging me out, So I saw that there was 1,418 updates so I installed them then after that I restarted the computer and I logged in and all that I saw was only my background picture of my desktop... Nothing else just the picture.

Comment: So.... What's the question?

Comment: Brennan - you appear to have multiple accounts.  Please register one of these accounts and then click the contact-us link at the bottom of this page to merge your other accounts.  Once done you'll be able to re-edit your question to add further details.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Follow these steps**

- When you system opens press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to go to `tty1` CLI Mode.
- Login with your credentials
- Execute these commands in series(one by one):

  ```
  sudo apt-get autoremove
  sudo apt-get autoclean
  sudo apt-get -f install
  sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
  ```

  If you get any error in any particular command, just mention it with the error message. All the commands should execute without any error.
- Now execute following command:

  ```
  sudo dpkg --configure -a
  sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
  ```

  One list will open which will prompt to chose the display manger. Chose `lightdm` from the list and then `ok`. You'll need to press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to highlight `Ok`.
- Then restart your system by following command:

  ```
  sudo reboot
  ```

After reboot your system should work fine.. Reply if something goes wrong or for further assistance..

Comment: Thanks it works! But I've noticed that it is really laggy! Is there a way that the lag can be fixed?

Comment: I am glad to help you.. I recommend you to start a new question. Since this issue is solved you should mark it as solved. To do so you've to accept my answer.. And don't forget to mention the complete information of your problem..