# Ubuntu not showing GUI

Tags: gui

I did install Ubuntu 13.10 on my old PC. Everything went fine except for when I login into my account there is no menubar, no icon bar, just only my wallpaper. I can do thing like creating a new folder and even access settings (so I did setup my internet connection) and I can access the log thingy (forget how to call it) by pressing ctrl+alt+F1, but I can't do anything else with it. I had this same issue also when I did try to Install Ubuntu in the past (that was version 12.Idontknowanymore). I did spend this whole evening searing how to fix this on the internet, but without any succes.

My computer isn't really super, I think it has about 1GB RAM, and the original OS is Windows XP (I did pick the 32Bit version of Ubuntu).

Does anyone knows how I can fix this problem and start using Ubuntu?
Thanks

Sincerely,
Random Use

Comment: Click this link and read the answer.
http://askubuntu.com/questions/359118/updated-stuff-with-updatemanager-problem?noredirect=1#comment459870_359118

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try installing XUbuntu at http://xubuntu.org/

It is a lighter version of Ubuntu.

Honestly, Ubuntu 32-bit should install just fine.  I recommend running Xubuntu or Ubuntu 32-bit as a liveCD first to see if that works fine.  If those run without problems, there maybe a bug that needs to get fixed.